# Django form displays form object as string

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a jqGrid that has a button to create a new row.  Instead of the Django form that I expect to show up, it just brings up a dialog that says "< views.export_view.ExportTemplateForm instance at 0xb1b2beec>"

HTML:

```
<div id="add-template-form-div" style="display:none">
<form method="post" name="templateform" id="template-form" title="Template Details">
<table><tbody>
{{export_template_form}}
</tbody></table>
</form>
<div class="form_loading">Adding Template...</div>
<div class="form_error"></div>
<div>
```

view:

```
#set other variables
infoDict['export_template_form'] = ExportTemplateForm()
#infoDict gets passed into render_response

class ExportTemplateForm():
    id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta(renderutils.BaseModelForm.Meta):
        model = ExportTemplate
```

Any tips?

Comment: Im on mobile so im not going to post this an answer because im surely missing something. But get rid of the table tags and do {{export_template_form.as_table}}

Comment: You need to inherit from `forms.ModelForm` - looks like you are not

Comment: @karthikr, thanks, I forgot I needed the class to be ExportTemplateForm(renderutils.BaseModelForm)